# Issues Looping through an array in Active Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to implement a feature which allows user to send one email to multiple recipients. I split the `recipient email` params by calling the `.split` method which turns it into an array. Then I loop through the array with the each method which should apply the mail method to each element in the array. The controller and mailer code is given below.

**controller code**

```
 def create
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @invitation = @scoreboard.sent_invitations.build(invitation_params)
    if @invitation.save
            UserMailer.registered_invitation_email(@scoreboard, @invitation).deliver_now
            flash[:success] = "Invitation sent successfully"
            redirect_to new_scoreboard_invitation_path
        else
            render 'new'
    end
    end
end
```

**mailer code**

```
def registered_invitation_email(scoreboard, invitation)
     @scoreboard = scoreboard
     @invitation = invitation
     split_email = @invitation.recipient_email.split
     split_email.each do |email|
       mail(to: email, subject: "View scoreboard")
    end

  end
```

The problem is that it only sends the email to the last element in the array. For example, if the user types in `"joe@example.com Mike@example.com"` in the form it will only send an email to the last element in an array. In this case, `Mike@exapmle.com`. I am not sure why that is. I think I am looping through it correctly. I am not sure what's causing the problem. I am not sure if its the loop or maybe loops don't work in active mailer. Not exactly sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Try putting `sleep 1` after sending a mail. see if it works.

Comment: @Harry Bomrah Sorry but I have never used sleep 1, where would I exactly put it, Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `split_email` as the value for `to:`? If the reason is, that each email must go to single recipient separately, you must invoke the mailer in the controller for each recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Create a model with fields

```
field :mail_to
field :subject
```

create a method in the same model

```
def deliver
   UserMailer.send_invitation_mail(self).deliver
end
```

Mailer

```
def send_invitation_mail(email)
   mail(to: email.mail_to, subject: email.subject)
   email.destroy
end
```

Controller

```
def create
  user_emails.each do |email|
      email = Email.new(:mail_to => "xxx@yyy.com",:subject => "View Scoreboard") # Email is the model name. 
      email.deliver
      sleep(1)
  end 
end
```

This way u can also log and also deliver all mails together in the model and also do various manipulations on the email.

Comment: @ Harry Bomrah No, that didn't work. It still sends to the last element in the array.

Comment: are you 100% sure that split_email is an array of all the emails. you might want to check what it has exactly.

Comment: @ Harry Bomrah Ok so this is how I went about doing this. First I wrote this code in invitations controller.  '@invitation = @invitation.recipient_email.split'. Then It gave me the following error.                                            undefined method `save' for ["divjot@example.com", "kuljinder_d@hotmail.com"]:Array. It gave me an error because I had two @invitation variables. However, It revealed to me that it was an array. I changed the @invitation variable to split_email. Nothing else changed. I moved it to action mailer and ran a code block to loop.

Comment: that doesnt answer if ur split_email has all the emails. did u check what is it exaclty

Comment: i ll edit my answer and try this. u ve to loop in controller or helper whatever u like.